# Button aligned to bottom of RelativeLayout is cut off

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

I have a button in my RelativeLayout that is being cut off when I use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` but nothing else I try is working correctly either. Any ideas?

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.cdar.sab.cdar.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/diagnostics_title" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint"
        android:id="@+id/emailTB" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailTB"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:hint="@string/message_hint"
        android:maxLines="10"
        android:id="@+id/messageTB" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say cut off? Can you post some screenshots? Is it not showing up at all or some edge is cut off?

Comment: @AnkitSharma I can't right now but I may be able to tomorrow. But basically it is as if the view extends outside the bounds of the display. Only the top tip of the button shows. The rest is cut off.

Comment: Your layout is ok.

Comment: @azizbekian That is what I thought but only the top portion of the button is displayed on the screen of my phone. The rest is cut off.

Comment: May the `Tools` -> `Layout Inspector` be with you.

Comment: @azizbekian I'm not sure what good that is going to do. It just tells me what I have set for the button, which I already know that it is set to align to the bottom of its parent.

Comment: @azizbekian Am I missing something on that then?

Comment: That layout is apparently for your `PlaceholderFragment`. Are you sure `PlaceholderFragment`'s container isn't being overlapped by another `View`? Or possibly extending outside of its parent?

Comment: @MikeM. I am using the tabbed app template in Android studio so the views are inside fragments. I guess that would make the view lower than normal since there is a bar at the top. Is there a way to work around that so that the button will display correctly on all screens? Maybe a way to get the height of the tab bar and add that as padding?

Comment: please post the screenshot

Comment: Post a simple project demonstrating that behaviour in github.

Comment: Please add screenshot, your view might be distorted due to large text inside EditText or TextView. For better you can use ScrollView as a root view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really difficult to understand why UI is distorted there can be many reasons of that but which I highly suspect is limit of text is exceeding in your input boxes which causing UI distortion. Please add screenshot for better understanding. So according to it I tried to reduce text sizes and margins between the views to make sure UI not distort if that was due to few margin.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Diagnostic"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailTB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Hint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/messageTB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailTB"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Hint"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Changing the text size in my textview allowed the view to fit inside of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You have given layout padding in your main container .i.e

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Adding margin instead of padding will solve your problem.Give a try to below code

```
android:marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: This did not work. It just made the spacing really weird.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a screenshot to better understand the problem, well if half of the button is hiding behind the onscreen navigation bar (as some devices has onscreen navigation bar and other's outside of screen) then add this line in your RelativeLayout `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` or you may use code to hide navigation bar.

Comment: I will try adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" and get back to you on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I modified your layout using LinearLayout, hope it will work for you.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.cdar.sab.cdar.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/diagnostics_title" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailTB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageTB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/message_hint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I will try this out and see if it is the change that I need to make. Thanks!

Comment: How about instead making the EditText 0dp height and layout_weight=1, you insert a plain View between the edittext and the button with 0dp height and layout_weight=1. Not 100% sure but I think your solution would cause the EditText text to be placed at the bottom or the center of the view which might look odd.

Comment: My solution works for me even with variable height dialogs, for example if it contains an expandable list.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use the layout in a PlaceholderFragment. I had the same problem with an adapter in a fragment. You should try to constrain the button with the second EditText and then run the code(quick fix). I think the problem is that when you run the code in a Fragment the layout is shifted and match_parent is computed as the whole screen(or the activity's size) thus aligning the button with the parent Activity and then it moves the layout down to make room for the tabs labels.
[The layout looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq44A.png)

Comment: I'm just not sure how I will do this and keep it aligned to the bottom on all different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.cdar.sab.cdar.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/diagnostics_title" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailTB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/email_hint"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageTB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailTB"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/message_hint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="10" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlContainer">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This looks fine in the layout preview but has the same issue as mine when I load it on a device.

Comment: Try giving margin bottom to the relative layout having the button.

Comment: That works as expected. It will look fine for the device I am currently setting the margin for but other screen sizes will not be the same. I need this to be consistent across screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a outer relative layout to your Button

```
<RelativeLayout..............>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/content_rl>
    <!-- Some ELEMENTS -->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/content_rl">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That is the same thing that Inderpreet Singh said to do and it did not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some Title" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:hint="Some hint"
    android:id="@+id/emailTB" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailTB"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:hint="Some hint"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:id="@+id/messageTB" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/messageTB"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

May be you could try giving marginBottom to your Button

```
 android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
```

Comment: The issue with this is that the spacing will not match across all screen sizes.